# I need to check Date Range entered by user is overlapping dates already present in datatable

Tags: c#, date

I have a data table with column From Date and To Date.
User entered date using two date time picker dtFrom and dtTo. 
I need to check if date entered by user is overlapping From Date and To Date column present in data table. e.g.
columns in data table

```
FromDate     ToDate
01/07/2012   30/06/2013
01/07/2013   30/06/2014
01/07/2015   30/06/2016
```

Now if user enter

```
From Date    ToDate
01/07/2012   30/06/2017
```

I wanted to check if these dates entered by user are overlapping with dates present in data table.

Below are lines of my code that help me out to check if the dates entered by using lies in between any of date ranges present in data table.

```
if (dbMaster.Table.Select("AC04_FROM_DATE <= "
    + dtFrom.GetDateTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 
    + " AND AC04_TO_DATE >= " 
    + dtTo.GetDateTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#'").Length > 1)
{
      e.Message = "Entered Financial Period is already selected. Please enter other Financial Period.".ToLocalString();
      e.IsValid = false;
}
```

But my condition doesn't let me know if the date entered by used is over lapping with any of date ranges present in datatable.

Please guide and suggest me a solution for c# desktop application

Comment: To check if two ranges overlap you use the following check `Range1.EndDate > Range2.StartDate && Range1.StartDate < Range2.EndDate`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and tell us what went wrong. This is not a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: Iterate the data table and check for overlapping?

Comment: Beg your pardon. This is what I have tried up till now. if (dbMaster.Table.Select("AC04_FROM_DATE <= '#" + dtFrom.GetDateTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + 
                "#' AND AC04_TO_DATE >='#" + dtTo.GetDateTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#'").Length > 1)
            {   -- This condition tells me if what user has entered lies in the between the date ranges datatable already has ..

Comment: I have edited by question with the code I am using. Please check if you get to know what I have achieved & what else I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick copy from what I used in a project recently to check 2 DateTime objects that had originally come from date pickers for overlaps.

```
//Myobject contains:
//DateTime dtStart
//DateTime dtEnd

//toAdd is object I want to check (what the user just entered)
//myList is a List<MyObject> whose start and end dates I need to check against for overlaps.
 private bool CheckForTimeClashes(MyObect toAdd)
 {
    bool overlap = false;
    foreach(MyObect ri in myList)
    {
        overlap = toAdd.dtStart < ri.dtEnd && ri.dtStart < toAdd.dtEnd;
        if (overlap)
            return true;
    }
    return overlap;            //false        
 }
```

I then just called this for all the objects I wanted to check.  in my case once I found an overlap then I could return

Comment: foreach (DataRow datarow in dbMaster.Table.Rows)
{
if (datarow.RowState == DataRowState.Unchanged)
{
if (Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["AC04_FROM_DATE"]) < dtTo.GetDateTime() &&
                                          dtFrom.GetDateTime() < Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["AC04_TO_DATE"]))
                    {
                        e.Message = "overlapping";
                        e.IsValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                }
         }

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Obviously it will not be exactly what you want but you get the idea.

```
var overlapping = false;

DataColumn fromCol = dataTable.Columns["FromDate"];
DataColumn toCol = dataTable.Columns["ToDate"];

foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
    //Add your logic here
    overlapping = DateTime.Parse(row[fromCol]) < Range1.Startdate;
    overlapping = DateTime.Parse(row[toCol]) < Range1.Enddate;
}
```